# Any way to specify default settings for log4net appenders?

Tags: c#, log4net

i.e. I have several RollingFileAppender instances configured via app.config; they omit some params and I want to apply default settings to these params of all instances (if they don't specify this setting explicitly). Any way to do this?

Comment: You can [configure the appenders at runtime](http://blog.gfader.com/2010/05/log4net-how-to-change-settings-of.html)

Answer (score 0):

After initializing log4net you can get the appenders and change properties on then:

```
var appenders = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders();
```

Now you will be able to get the RollingFileAppender by:

```
var rolingfileappenders = appenders.Where(a => a is typeof(RollingFileAppender));
```

Next you can change properties:

```
foreach ( RollingFileAppender rolingfileappender in rolingfileappenders)
{
    //change your stuff here
}
```

Comment: I don't know what params are set from the config file and what are initialized with log4net defaults, in this case. So, I don't know what params to init with my defaults and what params to keep.